# Cache a using statement, does it get disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, caching

I have a db query that is surrounded by a using statement to dispose the connection to the db after it's done. This works perfect. Now I want to cache the results of this. Is it correct to cache the using statement or should I have the cache inside the using statement? Will the connection be disposed correctly?

```cs
return _cacheManager.GetAndCache(CacheKey, CacheTime, () => {
                using (var connection = this._dataContext.GetDbConnection())
                {     
                    return this._dataContext.Execute();
                }
});
```

Comment: You just using context to get data, and thar data is stored in cache, let say that you return a database object from it, than you tried to get some additional data using foreign key (virtual list in your entity objevt class), you will get an error that database context is disposed.

Comment: @Djuro I thought that was the case. Thank you for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

This all comes down to what the lifetime expectations of `GetDbConnection()` are. There are two possibilities:

- it returns a separate and isolated connection every time `GetDbConnection()` is called - in which case the *caller* is the owner, and it is correct to `Dispose()`, so: use `using` in the way shown in the question
- it returns the *same* shared connection each time, perhaps lazily creating it when necessary (i.e. it hasn't been instantiated yet); in this case it is *incorrect* to `Dispose` it, since you aren't the owner

I *suspect* the answer is "the second one", but to find out as a brief test / experiment:

```cs
var x = this._dataContext.GetDbConnection();
var y = this._dataContext.GetDbConnection();
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(x, y));
```

Only dispose (i.e. use `using`) if this returns `false`. If it returns `true`, then we can reasonably assume that the data-context itself is retaining ownership of the connection, and the data-context will dispose it when appropriate (i.e. when the data-context is disposed, assuming the data-context created the connection).

Comment: I was a bit unclear I guess. The question was really about if the dbconnection would be disposed correctly even if the "whole" using statement is being cached. I don't think it's a problem, but just wanted to check if someone saw a problem with it.

To answer you question; the connection is separate and isolated with each GetDbConnection.

Comment: It will get disposed, even if you have return inside of it, hidden finally block of IDisposable will call Dispose() method

Comment: And you are not caching using statement, you are caching value that is returned via that using

Comment: @Djuro I thought that was the case. Thank you for the confirmation.